# PowerShell script to list items in collection

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and am trying to query against my SQL server. I get the idea of creating a new-psdrive and then navigating to databases etc and have a line of code as

> $dbs = (get-childitem
>   sqlserver:\sql\SERVER\INSTANCE\databases)

when I pipe the $dbs to a foreach, how would I get results of a collection of the database object? I am trying to read the extendedproperties of my test database.

This single query gives the results I want repeated for each database.

> set-location
>   DRIVENAME:\databases\beagle_test\extendedproperties
>   get-childitem | select displayname,
>   value

any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, many years later I am looking into my SO stats and see this old question and figure that my powershell skills have grown a little since 2010.

The use-case has long gone but I *think* what I was trying to achieve is this:

```
foreach ($db in $SMOServer.databases | Where-Object status -eq 'normal') {
    $db.ExtendedProperties | Select-Object @{name = "DBName"; expression = {$db.Name}}, name, value
}
```

which gives results like this:

```
DBName                 Name                                 Value
------                 ----                                 -----
AdventureWorks2014     MS_Description                       AdventureWorks 2014 Sample OLTP Database
AdventureWorks2016     MS_Description                       AdventureWorks 2016 Sample OLTP Database
```

Answer (score 1):

## I dont have SQL server handy to try this. Let me know the result

Set-Location DRIVENAME:\Databases

Get-ChildItem | % { Get-ChildItem $("$_.Name\extendedproperties") | Select DisplayName, Value }

Comment: Pretty close, this error for each database: Get-ChildItem : Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
At line:6 char:34
+ Get-ChildItem | % { Get-ChildItem <<<<  $("$_.Name\extendedproperties") | Sel
ect DisplayName, Value }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentOutOf 
   RangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: can  you explain the | % please? My help file doesnt return any results when I search for it...

Comment: Aah...so, the $_.Name isn't there. What do u see when you run Get-ChildItem at DRIVENAME:\Databases ? what is the name of the column that shows your database name?

BTW, % is foreach-object. It is just a shorthand notation

Comment: yeah, got the | on its own, whats the % that follows it?

Not all db's will have extended properties, I think thats where the problem is ...

Comment: gci after sl gives every property for every database. gci | select name gives name of every database

Comment: that explains then. So, we need to first find out if extendedproperties exist and then do something. Like I said % is a shorthand for ForEach-Object

Comment: sorry, just re-read your 1st comment and saw that at the end. Yes, we need to test the extendedproperties collection for each database. IsEmpty? IsNull? only have VB and SQL experience to draw on :-/

Comment: Sorry..added another answer by mistake..check that

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

Set-Location DRIVENAME:\Databases

Get-ChildItem | foreach-object { if (Test-Path $("$*.Name\extendedproperties")) { Get-ChildItem $("$*.Name\extendedproperties") | Select DisplayName, Value } }

The second line here is a single statement. What I am doing is to check if Extendedproperties exist and then get child item.

Comment: At line:6 char:47
+ Get-ChildItem | foreach-object { if (Test-Path <<<<  -path $("$.Name\extendedproperties\displayname")) { Get-ChildItem $("$.Name\extendedproperties") | Select Displ
ayName, Value } }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (SQLSERVER:\sql\...ies\displayname:SqlPath) [Test-Path], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : KeysNotMatching,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Comment: tried adding "displayname" (see above) but original gives same error for each database

Comment: I am lost too..I need to look at the properties at this point..Is it possible to paste the output of Get-ChildItem DRIVERNAME:\Databases?

Comment: is there a way to only get one set, rather than for each db?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your last comment

Comment: gci output only fits in new answer !

Comment: ExtendedProperties : {} seems to null. Do u have a DB for which this property shows something? I want to find out what type of data is this? Looks like a hash to me

Comment: yes there is database that I have added them specifically to test this

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dir sqlserver:\sql\ServerName\InstanceName\Databases\*\ExtendedProperties\* | 
  select @{Name="Database";Expression={$_.Parent.Name}}, Name, Value
```

Comment: (I should mention... I tested this on a system on which some, but not all, databases had extended properties)

Comment: This is crazy, I still get an error ::>> Get-ChildItem : Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
At line:5 char:4
+ dir <<<<  sqlserver:\sql\myservername\myinstancename\databases\*\ExtendedProperties\* | select @{Name="Database";Expression={$_.Parent.Name}}, Name, Value
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: You've missed a slash. Databases\*\ExtendedProperties - with a slash after Databases, before the star.

Comment: Oh... SO is removing it maybe. It dropped it from my comment too.

Comment: not noticed that before. I had the slashes as per your answer (copy/paste). My error had same slashes but SO has dropped them as escape chars I think

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\Server\Instance\databases\*\extendedproperties\* | % {select $_.displayname, $_.value}
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Not all db's have extendedproperties :: Get-ChildItem : Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
At line:12 char:4
+ dir <<<<  SQLSERVER:\SQL\Server\Instance\databases\*\extendedproperties\* | % {select $_.displayname, $_.value}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand